# Common Letters between Two Strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, increment

I'm trying to count the number of common letters between the user's `input` and the number generated. I am counting it so that the placement doesn't matter between them (so 411 and 004 should say "1 number in common").

I've placed my `code` in a snippet below. It works fine, except for that, *when the generated `string` has two of the same numbers, it doesn't work properly.* You can see that by typing "4", it will say that there are two chars. in common, when there is really only one (it counts the four twice.)

So, after all this, I'm asking **what is the best way to show the common letters between the `input` and the `generated number?`**

I'm fine with using `jQuery` and/or `JavaScript`, and sorry if my code isn't very good, I'm not very advanced at all.

Thanks for any help in advance! :)

```js
  // on ".check" click...

$(".check").click(function() {
  var nmb = $(".number").text();
  var ltr = $(".input").val();
  var count = $(".cnt");

  // Set logged text to 0
  
  count.text("0");

  // Test for numbers in common

  if (ltr.includes(nmb.charAt(0))) {
    count.html(function(i, val) {
      return val * 1 + 1
    });
  }
  if (ltr.includes(nmb.charAt(1))) {
    count.html(function(i, val) {
      return val * 1 + 1
    });
  }
  if (ltr.includes(nmb.charAt(2))) {
    count.html(function(i, val) {
      return val * 1 + 1
    });
  }
  if (ltr.includes(nmb.charAt(3))) {
    count.html(function(i, val) {
      return val * 1 + 1
    });
  }
  
  $(".res1").html(" numbers in common");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Generated Number: <span class="number">4410</span><br><br>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Try typing 4 to see the issue" maxlength="4">
<input class="check" type="submit" value="CHECK">
<br><br>
<span id="full_res">
  <span class="cnt"></span>
  <span class="res1"></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```js
$(".check").click(function() {
  var nmb = $(".number").text().trim().split('');   //Get the text and convert to string
  var ltr = $(".input").val().trim().split('');     //Get the value and convert to string
  var commonLetters = [];                           //The common letters will be stored on this variable

  ltr.forEach(function(v) {                         //Loop thru the user's input letters
    var idx = nmb.indexOf(v);                       //Find its index
    if (idx !== -1) {                               //Check if found
      commonLetters.push(4);                        //If found, push the letters to commonLetters
      nmb[idx] = '';                                //Clear the index
    }
  })

  $(".cnt").text(commonLetters.length);
  $(".res1").html(" numbers in common");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Generated Number: <span class="number">4410</span><br><br>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Try typing 4 to see the issue" maxlength="4">
<input class="check" type="submit" value="CHECK">
<br><br>
<span id="full_res">
   <span class="cnt"></span>
   <span class="res1"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm marking this as the answer because it's the simplest one that's functional to my desire.

Answer (score 3):

First you can reduce each of the strings to only include unique characters, ie 4410 can be reduced to 410 as you don't need to test 4 more than once. You can do this by creating a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of each string:

```
var numberSet = new Set(nmb);
var inputSet = new Set(ltr);
```

Then you can iterate over one of them, for least amount of iterations which ever is shortest, and use the [`has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) method to see if that character was in the other `Set`

```
var counter = 0;
for(letter of inputSet){
  if(numberSet.has(letter)){
    counter++;
  }
}
```

```js
// on ".check" click...

$(".check").click(function() {
  var nmb = new Set( $(".number").text() );
  var ltr = new Set( $(".input").val() );
  var count = $(".cnt");

  var counter = 0;
  for(let letter of nmb){
     if(ltr.has(letter)){
       counter++;
     }
  }
  //No need to continually update text / html as each update wont be
  //seen anyway so just set it once outside the loop.
  count.text(counter);
  
  $(".res1").html(" numbers in common");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Generated Number: <span class="number">4410</span><br><br>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Try typing 4 to see the issue" maxlength="4">
<input class="check" type="submit" value="CHECK">
<br><br>
<span id="full_res">
  <span class="cnt"></span>
  <span class="res1"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: This works, but when I type "44", then it still says 1 in common, when really it should say two. Thanks for helping though :)

Comment: @aman.s well 4 and 4 are the same character so there is only 1 common character. If you are wanting number of occurrences that is a bit different I can change it to update it.

Comment: @aman.s actually what is to happen then if you put in 404 should it still be 3, 2, or 1 since the 0 and 4 are not in the same order in the `nmb`? Does position of the characters in each string matter?

Comment: I specified that the order doesn't matter, so typing in 404 should be "3" because the 2 fours and the 1 zero is in common ;)

Comment: And there is an answer that accounts for the 'both fours as one char.' problem, but thanks! If you want to do it anyway, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely trivial. For example, you can't simply use `filter` or `includes` or `has` tests on their own because once a character is found, you have to remove it from *each* collection so it doesn't get matched again. I would use `reduce` and `splice` the array of characters to remove the found character every time a match is found. (No need for jQuery for this)

```js
document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const numChars = [...document.querySelector('.number').textContent];
  const inputChars = [...document.querySelector('.input').value];
  const matchingCharCount = inputChars.reduce(
    ({ remainingNumChars = numChars, matchCount = 0 } = {}, inputChar) => {
      if (remainingNumChars.includes(inputChar)) {
        remainingNumChars.splice(remainingNumChars.indexOf(inputChar), 1);
        matchCount++;
      }
      return { remainingNumChars, matchCount };
    }, { remainingNumChars: numChars, matchCount: 0 })
    .matchCount;
  document.querySelector('.cnt').textContent = matchingCharCount;
  document.querySelector('.res1').textContent = " numbers in common"
});
```

```html
Generated Number: <span class="number">4410</span><br><br>
<input type="text" class="input" maxlength="4">
<input class="check" type="submit" value="CHECK">
<br><br>
<span id="full_res">
  <span class="cnt"></span>
  <span class="res1"></span>
</span>
```